# Visual Studio Immediate Window .load sos.dll doesn't work

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windbg

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Immediate Window to see some objects' memory layout.

First, I created a Console Application Project and changed the Project Properties： checked the `Enable native code debugging` check box at the `Debug` tag. Second, I checked `Tools → Options → Debugging → Use Managed Compatibility Mode`. At last, I typed `load sos.dll` in the Immediate Window, after a while I get this output like this:

**Error during command: Warning. Extension is using a callback which Visual Studio does not implement.**

**Error during command: Exception c0000005 occurred at 2A667BA6**

I really don't know how to solve this problem and what is the meaning...

Answer (score 7):

I've recently got the same exact error message. It seems that Visual Studio tries to load wrong SOS.dll by default.

I loaded an earlier version of this dll, and now it works fine. Try this:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\sos.dll
```

If this folder not exist in your machine, try another version, which is available.

Hope this helps.